Postgresql package not available?
I am trying to install postgresql on a new Ubuntu 24.04 machine.  I'm surprised that after
$ sudo apt update
Hit:1 https://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable InRelease
Hit:2 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu noble-security InRelease                                          
Hit:3 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu noble InRelease                                                 
Get:4 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu noble-updates InRelease [126 kB] 
Get:5 https://esm.ubuntu.com/apps/ubuntu noble-apps-security InRelease [7,532 B]
Hit:6 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu noble-backports InRelease   
Get:7 https://esm.ubuntu.com/apps/ubuntu noble-apps-updates InRelease [7,468 B]
Get:8 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu noble-updates/universe i386 Packages [167 kB]
Get:9 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu noble-updates/universe amd64 Packages [384 kB]
Get:10 https://esm.ubuntu.com/infra/ubuntu noble-infra-security InRelease [7,462 B]
Get:11 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu noble-updates/universe amd64 c-n-f Metadata [14.9 kB]
Get:12 https://esm.ubuntu.com/infra/ubuntu noble-infra-updates InRelease [7,461 B]
Fetched 721 kB in 1s (497 kB/s)       
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
All packages are up to date.

this fails:
$ sudo apt install postgresql
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
Package postgresql is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source

E: Package 'postgresql' has no installation candidate

As far as I can tell, this package should be available and the above is unexpected.  I must've done something to mess up my machine, but I'm not sure what.  Any help is appreciated.

Would this work for you? https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Apt It uses the postgress PPA

If I have to, I will go this route but I'd really like to figure out if this is expected or not.  If it is unexpected, I'd rather fix my distribution to avoid other errors in the future.

Have you run sudo apt-get update? If not, please run it and add the output here

Check that you have the main component in your sources list - in 24.04 that would be in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/ubuntu.sources by default

Agree with both @Rinzwind and @steeldriver that there is a package called postgresql-16 in the main repository for 24.04. That should be available to you.

Thanks for the confirmation that postgresql-16 should work.  I see an "i386" mentioned ("Get:8" in the update list) and I wonder if that is what caused this (I think this was added via install of steam)

apt install postgresql on a fresh Ubuntu Docker container results in postgresql (16+257build1.1) getting installed, so I suppose next thing do is check your sources: head -n-0 /etc/apt/sources.list /etc/apt/sources.list.d/*.{sources,list}, and apt-cache policy

I do not know how this happened but the "Software & Updates" app showed that somehow the "Canonical-supported free and open-source software (main)" was deselected.  Selecting, updating & installing then worked as expected.
Thanks to all who commented & let me know this should work.

